# Calling PHP from Smarty template

Tags: php, smarty

I am trying to integrate an ad package into my Smarty based site. I have been given the following PHP code that I need to add to my footer file.  But due to it being Smarty I need to add the code instead to my php file so that it can be called/included in my Smarty template file. This was the code that I was given and that I need to include:

```
    <?php if(function_exists('ad_footer')) ad_footer(); ?>
```

But in the php file I am not sure how to achieve this - I have got this example and wanted to know if it looked correct??

```
if(function_exists('ad_footer')) {
 ob_start();
 ad_footer();
 $smarty->assign('ad_footer', ob_get_clean());
```

}

Does the above look the right way to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and created a test page to see if the above worked and it did so will stick with this code.